# Discarding rows for particular column values for dyadic data

Tags: r

I have data that looks something like this:

```
cnme1 cnme2 year  midonging  midonset
USA   RUS   1945  0          0
USA   RUS   1946  0          1
USA   RUS   1947  1          0 
USA   RUS   1948  1          0
USA   RUS   1949  0          0
USA   UK    1945  0          0
USA   UK    1946  0          0
USA   UK    1947  0          0
.
.
.
USA  RUS   2010   0           0
```

Each row consists of a country-dyad year and variables for whether or not the country-dyad was involved in some sort of conflict. Some dyad-years (U.S.-Russia) have years of ongoing conflict, whereas others (U.S.-U.K.) have no conflict at all.

I want to subset the country-dyads that, at some point in time, were involved in some sort of conflict. So basically getting rid of any country-dyad (e.g. U.S.-U.K.) for which certain variables are coded '0' throughout time, and keep the ones where there was a conflict in during the dyad's history (e.g. U.S.-Syria or U.S.-Venezuela).

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(midonging + midonset != 0)

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   cnme1 cnme2  year midonging midonset
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 USA   RUS    1946         0        1
# 2 USA   RUS    1947         1        0
# 3 USA   RUS    1948         1        0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(cnme1 = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA"), cnme2 = c("RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "RUS", "UK", 
"UK", "UK"), year = c(1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1945, 1946, 
1947), midonging = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), midonset = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
df[rowSums(df[c("midonging", "midonset")]) >0,]
```